# How can aura components with open regions be nested inside custom theme layout components for communities?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, community-builder, custom-theme-layout

The only official reference for creating a custom theme layout components for communities I was able to found is from the [lighting aura components developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm).

In order to leave a region open for users to drag-and-drop components into an attribute declared as `Aura.Component[]` should be created and included in the markup.

e.g.

```
...
<aura:attrivute name="exampleRegion" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
...
<div>
  {!v.exampleRegion}
</div>
...
```

This works fine with an aura component that implements `forceCommunity:themeLayout`. What I trying to achieve is having nested aura components that have these regions.

e.g. A custom aura component that should act as compact header and is a variant of the Hero standard with regions for global search, navigation and profile menu. This compact header should be nested inside the custom theme layout.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?